# How do I solve the gcc error on finding pkg-config?

Tags: c, gcc, gtk3, msys2, pkg-config

This question seems to have been asked a zillion times, but unfortunately, none of the answers helped me.

I believe I have installed gtk correctly. My pkg-config environment seems okay. I'm not so sure of gcc.
I removed all the mingw and cygwin folders from my path environment, as I am only going to be using msys2 packages. So I have my path environment this way:-

GTK_LIB_DIR
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib

PKG_CONFIG_PATH
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\pkgconfig

Path - C:\msys64\usr\bin;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;%GTK_LIB_DIR%

The problem I am having is with compilation. Running this... 
***gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o gtkTest C:\dev\test_gtk3.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`***

I get...

```
cc: error: `pkg-config: No such file or directory
gcc: error: gtk+-3.0`: No such file or directory
gcc: error: `pkg-config: No such file or directory
gcc: error: gtk+-3.0`: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--cflags'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--libs'
```

I can run the following commands separately, with expected results. e.g.

```
pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0
pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
gcc -o gtkTest C:\dev\test_gtk3.c
```

Of course the last command returns an error, since gtk is not referenced.
I tried various combinations, some of my own. Some recommended, but one error persists, on pkg-config.
e.g.
C:\WINDOWS\system32>**gcc -o gtkTest C:\dev\test_gtk3.c "pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0"**

```
gcc: error: pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0: No such file or directory
```

The last answer I found says ["If pkg-config reports that it couldn't find the package, then you didn't install the Gtk development package as offered by your Linux distribution."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944866/how-to-compile-c-and-gtk-with-gcc-on-linux)

I'm using Windows, but I think I installed gtk correctly, since I followed the instructions, and I get what seems to be the expected results (please correct me if I am mistaken).

C:\WINDOWS\system32>***pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0***

```
-pthread -mms-bitfields -I/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0 -I/mingw64/include/cairo -I/m
ingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/pango-1.0 -I/mingw64/include/fribidi -I/mingw6
4/include -I/mingw64/include/atk-1.0 -I/mingw64/include/cairo -I/mingw64/include
/pixman-1 -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/freetype2 -I/mingw64/include -I/
mingw64/include/harfbuzz -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/libpng16 -I/mingw
64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include
 -I/mingw64/include/glib-2.0 -I/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/mingw64/include
```

C:\WINDOWS\system32>***pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0***

```
-L/mingw64/lib -L/mingw64/lib/../lib -L/mingw64/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lgdi32
-limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lep
oxy -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lm -lgdi32 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lm -lpangowi
n32-1.0 -lm -lusp10 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -lfribidi -lthai -ldatrie -latk-1.0
-lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lz -lpixman-1 -lm -pthread -lfontconfig -liconv -lexpat
 -lfreetype -lbz2 -lharfbuzz -lm -lusp10 -lgdi32 -lrpcrt4 -lgraphite2 -lpng16 -l
z -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lgio-2.0 -pthread -lintl -lshlwapi -ldnsapi -liphlpapi -
lws2_32 -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lintl -lz -lgobject-2.0 -pthread -lintl -lffi -l
glib-2.0 -lintl -lws2_32 -lole32 -lwinmm -lshlwapi -pthread -lm -lpcre
```

C:\WINDOWS\system32>***gcc -o gtkTest C:\dev\test_gtk3.c | pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0***

```
-pthread -mms-bitfields -I/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0 -I/mingw64/include/cairo -I/m
ingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/pango-1.0 -I/mingw64/include/fribidi -I/mingw6
4/include -I/mingw64/include/atk-1.0 -I/mingw64/include/cairo -I/mingw64/include
/pixman-1 -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/freetype2 -I/mingw64/include -I/
mingw64/include/harfbuzz -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/libpng16 -I/mingw
64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include
 -I/mingw64/include/glib-2.0 -I/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/mingw64/include
-L/mingw64/lib -L/mingw64/lib/../lib -L/mingw64/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lgdi32
-limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lep
oxy -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lm -lgdi32 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lm -lpangowi
n32-1.0 -lm -lusp10 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -lfribidi -lthai -ldatrie -latk-1.0
-lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lz -lpixman-1 -lm -pthread -lfontconfig -liconv -lexpat
 -lfreetype -lbz2 -lharfbuzz -lm -lusp10 -lgdi32 -lrpcrt4 -lgraphite2 -lpng16 -l
z -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lgio-2.0 -pthread -lintl -lshlwapi -ldnsapi -liphlpapi -
lws2_32 -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lintl -lz -lgobject-2.0 -pthread -lintl -lffi -l
glib-2.0 -lintl -lws2_32 -lole32 -lwinmm -lshlwapi -pthread -lm -lpcre
C:\dev\test_gtk3.c:1:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Has anyone here struggled with this for hours, like I have, and finally got to understand what the problem is.
Please share your solution. Thank you.

Comment: I seem to have found a workaround, but it doesn't explain why the command works for some, and not others.  I really would like to understand what the issue is. Here is a link to the page I found. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325552/compiling-and-running-gtk-application-on-windows-7

Comment: Your problem is not the `pkg-config` command but the usage of the result. Under Linux the command is enclosed in backticks to make the shell execute it and replace it with the result of the command. I don't know if this is possible under Windows as well. You might try to store outout of `pkg-config` in a variable and use that in your command line as suggested in the link you mentioned in previous comment

Comment: I thought those backticks were strange to windows. I couldn't even make them. I had to copy and paste. Yes, I used the method from the original - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450445/installing-gtk-and-compiling-using-gcc-under-windows?lq=1, and that got rid of those errors. I got other errors, but I'll try to work those out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this [Installing gtk and compiling using gcc under windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450445/installing-gtk-and-compiling-using-gcc-under-windows?lq=1) helped me get past the errors.
I used the following suggestion.

> "Instead of a batch file, you may find more convenient to create an
>   user environmental variable and store the flags in there, that way you
>   will be able to compile from within a normal command prompt."

So I created two new environment variables (e.g. GTK_FLAGS_VARS; GTK_LIBS_VARS), and pasted the outputs in the variable values. Then in path place %GTK_FLAGS_VARS%;%GTK_LIBS_VARS%
Afterward gcc -o gtkTest C:\dev\test_gtk3.c %GTK_FLAGS_VARS% %GTK_LIBS_VARS%